# What is a "Projectile"?

Tags: unity, terminology, projectile-physics

I don't know what a Projectile os.

I'm not sure whether a Projectile is a spawn point which spawn a number of object or a number of multiple objects.

I'm referring to this [website](https://www.studica.com/blog/how-to-create-a-projectile-in-unity).

How do I use Projectiles and what does it mean?

Comment: I don't get how you got that confused.
A projectile HAS a spawn point and  there are A NUMBER OF projectiles.
A projectile is, what the dictionary says. An arrow. a bullet, magical bolt, whatever

Answer (score 5):

[From dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/projectile):

> projectile[ pruh-jek-til, -tahyl ]
>
> noun
>
> 1. an object fired from a gun with an explosive propelling charge,
>      such as a bullet, shell, rocket, or grenade.
> 2. a body projected or impelled forward, as through the air.

In the context of game development, it's usually a small game object which is spawned by another object, moves in a predictable path (often but not always a straight line), is destroyed if it collides with a solid object and causes damage if that other object is an opponent of the object which spawned the projectile. Common examples are bullets, arrows, rockets or fireballs.

Projectiles in a 2d game (Enter the Gungeon):

[image: Projectile in Enter the Gungeon]

Projectiles in a 3d game (Overwatch):

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PqQabXm you say which is spawned by another object means  2nd image bullet spaen position is different?? see my link can you example or referance?? because i m not clear about projectile

Comment: @Grics I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking. I guess the language barrier between us is just too high.

Comment: my question don't know you? unity related question not another language My question is which is spawned by another object ex when i click mouse button and fire a bullet means which position i should fire??

Comment: It's your game, @Grics. You can fire from any position and to any position you like. You get to make the rules of your game. If you wanted to make a vacuum gun that fires projectiles from its target toward its wielder, that would be a totally valid thing for you to do. If you wanted to make an air strike tagging tool that always fires its projectiles from far above the play area, that would work too. There's no universal rule here, just conventions and your own design.

Comment: @DMGregory tiles and projectiles same or not. can u give suggestion??

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98045/discussion-on-answer-by-philipp-what-is-a-projectile).